# How to reduce visibility for auto-generated code

Tags: c#, visibility, ranorex

I have a bunch of auto-generated code (coming from Ranorex GUI testing tool) that exposes a public interface like the one below:

```
public partial class MessageBoxPopupAppFolder : RepoGenBaseFolder
{
  // Ranorex.Button exposes public methods like Click()
  public virtual Ranorex.Button ButtonYes
  {
    get
    {
      return _buttonyesInfo.CreateAdapter<Ranorex.Button>(true);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that I'm in the process of writing an intermediate layer that will look like the code below, and I expect the users of that code to not bypass it by directly calling the autogenerated code (that would most probably break complex business rules)

```
public class MyAdapter
{
  private MessageBoxPopupAppFolder _myMessageBox;

  public static void Acknowledge()
  {
    // some complex business rules
    _myMessageBox.ButtonYes.Click();
  }
}
```

I have though of some solutions, but none seem really satisfactory:

- Manually (or through a script) modify auto-generated code to change visibility of Ranorex methods. That would imply a little namespace refactoring, and be difficult to maintain through code re-generation
- Link this code into a completely separate binary and communicate with it through a really private API. Lots of work ahead
- Implement some kind of code self-evaluation that would detect and report (as unit test failure) any "forbidden" use of that API

What could I do?

Just to clarify: I'm not concerned about keeping my middleware secret, just need to keep control over correct sequence on actual clicks.

**EDIT**: What I want to expose to my team members (users of my middleware) is a business-oriented API (like `Acknowledge()`). This is fine. What is not fine is that I can't prevent the Ranorex raw API (`Button.Click()`) to come along.

Comment: Why do you need to hand the clients the autogenerated classes directly, and not some limited interface you devise? Seems like that would be the traditional approach here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @millimoose : I do hand them a meaningful API. But I can't prevent my application to ALSO hand them a bad button-oriented API. See Edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to be safe, your best choice would be your first one, using script to modified the auto-generated code. Add the script into your integrated build process to ensure this get runs all the time in case the code go regenerated.
2. Other wise you can set up FxCop rule to detect method calls that you don't want to be used.
3. If the team is small and they are comfortable with following a design guideline. Then this is a matter of training team not to use the API. In your code review process your team will have to look for this issue. The drawback is that this is only a preventive action, your team member can still make mistake. QA and code review will be your best friend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ranorex doesn't support modifying the visibility of the generated members?

Number one definitely sounds like the way to go, since it seems to be directly what you are looking for.

Comment: I wish it could change the visibility itself, but found no clue yet on how

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are "too deep" into the design to solve this with an elegant and completely clean solution. All the alternatives will have their own drawbacks, one that I can suggest is to have an adapter/facade classes for the Ranorex types that you expose in your own classes. These adapters would then take care of some logic and then route the call to the true underlying Ranorex object. In the case of your `Acknowledge` example, that would be a method on the adapter and the public type you expose would only be the adapter.

Ideally, I'd hope for a Click event in the Button class so that you could listen to it and react accordingly.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. My problem is that I can't prevent people from writing `RanorexObject.MessageBox.Click()` instead of `MyAdapter.Acknowledge()`